# listing exceptions programmatically - Python

Tags: python

Is there any way to programmatically determine which exceptions an object or method might raise?

Like `dir(obj)` lists available methods, I'm looking for the equivalent `dir_exceptions(obj)`.

As far as I know, the only way to achieve this would be to parse the source.

Comment: Consider that the method might call library functions which themselves might raise arbitrary exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python and Exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283757/python-and-exceptions) (see comments on Noufal's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. An exception is a runtime phenomenon and you'll know what it possible (or what happens) only while running. Why would you want to do this though?

Comment: I bet wants to do something like: `try { blah() } catch dir_exceptions(blah) {  }`

Comment: It's definitively not possible. In Python it would even be possible to generate the exception class on the fly, based on some strange random data. That makes no sense of course, but it would be possible. ;-)

Comment: @Civilian: Python is not Java. The Python equivalent of that is `try: blah` <newline/tab> `except: blah`

Comment: @nmichaels or (usually) better: `except Exception:`.

Comment: @nmichaels: I'm giving the benefit of doubt and assume he's using braces for blocks simply because they are far easier to write and read in *SO comments* due to the lack of newlines. At least I do it whenever I need to embed multi-line code snippets in comments. And I don't even know Java ;)

Comment: Use case would be more for testability, or understanding a new library where maybe the docs aren't complete, without having to resort to the source.

Comment: @CNK: Then you should read [Python and Exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6283757/395760) (and consider whether yours is actually a duplicate - it seems so to me).

Comment: I can see where you're coming from but given pythons dynamic nature, I don't think you can do this.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, this is a dup, and you provided an excellent answer in the other. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @CNK: No need to delete it if we can get it closed as duplicate - better odds for both questions to be found (be it via search or when asking a new question).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you'll have to trust the code's developers on this one:  if they did a good job, the method/class documentation should list all the exceptions that could be raised.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a practical way to do this.

Most python developers derive from Exception, so if you're not sure, just catch Exception.

```
try:
    some_secret_code()
except Exception:
    print 'oops, something happened'
```

If you're thinking that you can import a module and poke around looking for things derived from Exception, that won't quite work either.  What about that python nut that does this ->

```
exec "raise SystemExit()"
```

I'm not sure that there is a non-practical way to accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible either, but if you trust that the programmer has named their exceptions with "`Exception`" or "`Error`" in the name, then you could do a `dir` on the class and search for elements that end with "`Exception`" or "`Error`". Aside from that (which is pretty hacky in itself), I don't see a straightforward/native/idiomatic way to do this

Comment: Exceptions are instances of their own classes, and it would be extremely unusual to make an exception class or instance a member of another class. Usually you create an exception locally and anonymously and raise it immediately: `raise ValueError( "illegal value" )`